# MySQL error: Can't find symbol '_mysql_plugin_interface_version_' in library

Tags: mysql, sphinxsearch

The boring, necessary details: I'm on Snow Leopard running `MySQL` locally.

I'm trying to install the `Sphinx` engine for `MySQL` like so:

```
mysql> install plugin sphinx soname 'sphinx.so';
ERROR 1127 (HY000): Can't find symbol '_mysql_plugin_interface_version_' in library
```

I've Googled everywhere and can't seem to find an actual solution to this problem. For example [this issue on the Sphinx forums](http://www.sphinxsearch.com/forum/view.html?id=4920) seems unresolved. Someone else also raised this issue with similar results.

The first post linked to an O'Reilly article which says:

> There is a common problem that might occur at this point:
>   ERROR 1127 (HY000): Can't find symbol '_mysql_plugin_interface_version_' in library
>   If you see a message like this, it is likely that you forgot to include the -DMYSQL_DYNAMIC_PLUGIN option when compiling the plugin. Adding this option to the g++ compile line is required to create a dynamically loadable plug-in.

But the article ends on that point; I have no idea what this means or how to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally had to just recompile MySQL entirely rather than install it as a plugin. This involved a number of gotchas in and of itself, too. But save yourself the headache of trying to recreate the same compile conditions for Sphinx that you used for MySQL and just recompile all at once following the Sphinx documentation to the letter.

Answer (score 1):

Please find the answer from [sphinx plugin compiling issue](http://techmanpoint.blogspot.com/2011/01/sphinx-plugin-compiling-issue-for-mysql.html). The solution is to remove --with-plugins=sphinx option when running configure, the option is used to build static library to mysql binary.